# Increment value by 1 inside array php

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
for($n = 0; $n <= 5; $n++)
 {
    $some =   $n+1 ;
 }
    $dataSubActivity[]=array(
    'showSubid' => $some,
    'activityMainId'=> $activityMainId,
    'activitySubTitle'=> $activitySubTitle,
    'descSub'=> $description,
    'unit'=> $unit,
    'quantity'=> $quantity);
```

the above code is an array i want to increment **"showSubid"** by 1
so the result should be 1,2,3,4 etc
please give some idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
for ($n = 0; $n <= 5; $n++) {
      // put it inside loop
      $dataSubActivity[]=array(
        'showSubid' => $n+1,
        'activityMainId'=> $activityMainId,
        'activitySubTitle'=> $activitySubTitle,
        'descSub'=> $description,
        'unit'=> $unit,
        'quantity'=> $quantity);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

USE THIS

```
for($n = 0; $n <= 5; $n++)
{
    $some =   $n+1 ;

    $dataSubActivity[]=array(
    'showSubid' => $some,
    'activityMainId'=> $activityMainId,
    'activitySubTitle'=> $activitySubTitle,
    'descSub'=> $description,
    'unit'=> $unit,
    'quantity'=> $quantity);
}
```